# finding max value within a file

Tags: c#

I need to find max value within each 1000 values in a file, i.e., if there is 5000 values within a file then there should be 5 max values. Within first 1000 values: one max value, then within next 1000 values one more max value.... and so on.

The size of the file will be unknown

I had prepared a code for finding max value within first 1000 values in the file. I was thinking of iterating it, to get the desired results, but could not. The codes are as follows.

```
List<Double> list = new List<Double>();
StreamReader dat = new StreamReader(file path);
//int count = 1;
string dataline = "";
for (int i = 1; i <= dat.BaseStream.Length; i+=1000)
{
    while ((dataline = dat.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Double sdat = Double.Parse(dataline);
        list.Add(sdat);
        richTextBox1.Text = list.Take(1000).Max().ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group the values on the index and get the max from each group:

```
List<double> max =
  File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
  .Select((s, i) => new KeyValuePair<int, double>(i, Double.Parse(s)))
  .GroupBy(x => x.Key / 1000, x => x.Value)
  .Select(g => g.Max())
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, but with a small bug; it should be: new KeyValuePair<int, double>

Comment: @varocarbas: Thanks, and good spot. I wrote code using integers when testing and forgot to change that one.